# Cursor is not moving when entering text

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am usuing edit field, but when I type any text in this field, then cursor in not moving with the text, It is showing typed text, but cursor position still remains on start .

I am using Os 6 and Os 7/7.1.

Please let me know for the problem.
Following is the image for it.

[image]

Comment: Are you facing this problem on the simulator alone?

Comment: I am facing this problem with both simulator and device.

Comment: Looks like it has been solved - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Adobe-AIR-Development/Set-Cursor-Position-for-TextInput/m-p/713161#M4153

Comment: Did you modify/override default implementation of `EditField`? If yes then you need to share the code.

Comment: Even if you didn't modify the implementation, code is a necessity to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added following code - onFocus and onUnFocus methods to the text field:

```
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    this.setCursorPosition(this.getTextLength());
    invalidate();
    super.onFocus(direction);
};

protected void onUnfocus() {
    this.setCursorPosition(this.getTextLength());
    invalidate();
    super.onUnfocus();
};
```

It has solved my problem.
Thanks to all for your support.